# Related to thymeleaf fragment using Spring boot

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, fragment, thymeleaf

I have an application using Spring boot and thymeleaf.
I have to display a menu in the header portion using database query and it should be displayed on every html template. If I use thymeleaf template fragment for the header menu, will the query be executed everytime a new html template is rendered? If everytime a menu query is fired on user request it will have lots of hits on the database. If I store the menu query in session object using @SessionAttribute, it will occupy a lot of memory. Require your guidance for the same.

Comment: I recommend caching the result of the `Service` function that passes the call to your `Repository`.  The way it works is that it returns the last result of the method if the input is the same.  You can set the length of time to keep the function cached.  Here are the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html

Comment: Thanks Joe Essey. I am checking on your solution.